# How to select only elements visible in the window

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Using jQuery, I want to change the color of all elements in the current window. The page scrolls, but I don't want elements scrolled off of the view - which I don't see - to be colored - only the elements in the current view window.

Comment: Why does it matter what color things you can't see are, just change the whole page's color..

Comment: the  paint is just an example. the idea is some operation for the current visible elements in the scroll position

Comment: See [How to tell if a DOM element is visible in the current viewport?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/123999/how-to-tell-if-a-dom-element-is-visible-in-the-current-viewport)

Comment: @GabyakaG.Petrioli Thanks. I already got that  , but couldnt delete the question. ( and the answer here is incorrect as u see)

Comment: @RoyiNamir, just added a custom jQuery selector implementation of that answer as an answer here..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a custom jQuery selector implementing the code from https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/128165

```
$.expr[':'].inViewport = (function(){
    function isElementInViewport (el) {
        var rect = el.getBoundingClientRect();

        return (
            rect.top >= 0 &&
            rect.left >= 0 &&
            rect.bottom <= (window.innerHeight || document.documentElement.clientHeight) && /*or $(window).height() */
            rect.right <= (window.innerWidth || document.documentElement.clientWidth) /*or $(window).width() */
        );
    }

    return function(obj, index, meta, stack){
       return isElementInViewport(obj);
    };
})();

//usage
$(':inViewport').css('color','red'); // color every element fully inside viewport
$('p:inViewport').css('color','red'); // color every paragraph element fully inside viewport
```

Answer (score 1):

Try ":visible" selector to select only the visible elements

Comment: it wont work , even visible elements which are down the scroll position - will be painted - which i dont want. i want only in currect window - in the scroll position. if i will scroll down - then i want the items to be painted in red.

Comment: Do you have any containers which contain the elements on the page. If yes then we can find out the scrolltop of these containers and see if they are within the current window view.

Comment: did you read the documentation for [`:visible`](http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/)? nowhere in there does it say anything about calculating whether the element is on the view-able portion of the screen.

Comment: @Greg - I very well know what ":visible" do. I didnt knew the user is looking for the elements in the current viewport which offcourse is not possible using this selector.